# Can I get one single array with one SQL selection with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a blog website and  want to display all my articles in my page. Those articles have an author and a translation (because this is a multiple language website).

Here are my tables

```
table : articles
rows :
- id
- release_date
- author_id

table : author
rows :
- id
- firstname
- lastname

table : translations
rows :
- id
- article_id
- translator_id
- translation_date
- language
- content
- title
```

I would like to display all information so I would like to have this type of array

```php
articles => array(
    0 => array(
        id => ...
        release_date => ...
        author => array (
            firstname => ...
            lastname => ...
        )
        translations => array (
            0 => array (
                translator => array (
                    firstname => ...
                    lastname => ...
                )
                translation_date => ...
                language => ...
                content => ...
                title => ...
            )
            1 => array(
                ...
            )
            ...
        )
    )
    1 => array(
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```

I would like all articles, order by `release_date` with the author and the last traduction in each language, for each traduction I want the translator

Is that possible in one query ?
Because For now i'm doing some loops and server taking a lot of times to answer (it's about 5 calls for each articles with 2 different languages, imagine with more than 100 articles...)

Comment: One query could get all of the desired data, but it couldn't construct an array like that.  You'd have to write code to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes but how can I accomplished this with one query ? Because all translations will have the same keys, and all tables have an id, so I lose some informations

Comment: What do you mean by "all translations will have the same keys"?  `SELECT ... FROM articles ar JOIN author au ON ar.author_id = au.id JOIN translations t ON t.article_id = ar.id JOIN author au2 ON t.translator_id = au2.id` (this assumes that you are housing translators in the `author` table)

Comment: Yes your query works but if i do `$article = query($your_query)` and then i want to get the id of the english translation for example, how can I do that ? because if i write `$articles["content"]` it will only give me the content of the first translation, they have the same keys so the value is override each time

Comment: Refer back to my original comment.  The query itself will only give you a list of all of the article/author/translation combinations.  You're going to have to write code to manipulate it into the array structure that you have in your question.  If you only want a certain language in your result-set, then put that in a `WHERE` clause in the query.

Comment: Mmmh okay i get it, and is that possible to select only some rows on joined table ?

Comment: Of course.  Same as if you were selecting from just one table.